# this.items[id].size.pop is not a function

Tags: arrays, node.js, express, methods, arr

I am trying to create an array of sizes. I am adding to the array just fine and it is displaying. I try to remove with `.pop();` and it gives me the error listed in the title of this post.

```
    this.add = function(item, id, size){
        var storedItem = this.items[id];

        if(!storedItem) {
            storedItem = this.items[id] = {item: item, qty: 0, price: 0, size: []}. <------
        }
        storedItem.size += size;
        storedItem.qty++;
        storedItem.price = storedItem.item.price * storedItem.qty;
        this.totalQty++;
        this.totalPrice += storedItem.item.price;
    }

    this.reduceByOne = function(id){
        this.items[id].size.pop().         <------------

        this.items[id].qty--;
        this.items[id].price -= this.items[id].item.price;
        this.totalQty--;
        this.totalPrice -= this.items[id].item.price;

        if(this.items[id].qty <= 0) {
            delete this.items[id];
        }
    }
```

I have also tried this and get the same error.

```
var reduceOne = this.items[id].size;
reduceOne.pop();
```

Comment: You are changing the array into another type at this line: ```storedItem.size += size;```... e.g. `[] + 1` yields `"1"`

Comment: that was the problem, its all fixed now, thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
storedItem.size += size;
```

Did you mean to use `push` here instead of `+=`?

```
storedItem.size.push(size);
```

Comment: dude. facepalm... yeah that fixed it. thank you so much.